# Xcode: automatically alpha-sort added files/groups/folders by name in Project Navigator

Tags: xcode

Is there a way of making Xcode automatically sort files/groups/folders by name when a project is created from existing artifacts, a folder is added to the project, or a bunch of files are added to a project?
The default behaviour is nonsensical and rather frustrating as it doesn't even match any sort criteria available in Finder.

**EDIT** Updated title to reflect what I really want answered.  I know how to sort after they've been added, its just a hassle to do it every time.

Answer (score 4):

These instructions are only tested on Xcode 13.  I don't know if this will work on other versions.

With the project open in Xcode:

1. Open the project navigator (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>).
2. Select the top-most folder you'd like to sort.
3. In the Xcode menu, select "Edit -> Sort".
4. Select the option to sort "By Name" or "By Type".

[image]

The files will then sort themselves according to your selection.

I don't know of any way to have Xcode sort the files by itself (ie creation of new project or immediately after adding/deleting a file).  Yes, this can be considered 'manual sorting' but it's all that Xcode offers at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with nice graphics, but it doesn't quite address the question, though you acknowledged that fact.  I want Xcode to load them into the project **already** in alphabetical order.  I'm sick of having to go through those steps every time I open a new set of files etc.  I'm hoping someone from Apple will notice this and be inspired.

Comment: The technique you've shown has been available for some time.  I'm currently using Xcode 12.4, and it was available well before that.

Comment: This is the only way to do it.  As I mentioned, it can't be done automatically.

Comment: I know that, but I want someone from Apple to take notice.

Comment: Then you're posting to the wrong forum.  Apple doesn't look here for product update ideas.  You need to contact Apple via [their Feedback page](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).  Your question will not receive an answer if you're "waiting for Apple to take notice", that's not what this site is about or how it should be used.